# Header Paperpunch theme disappers with IE9

Tags: themes

It's working fine with Firefox, Chrome and IE <= 8. But with IE9 the header disappears. Anybody an idea how to fix this?

It's about this theme: http://thethemefoundry.com/paperpunch/ and I'm using the free version

Comment: Tested with Chrome, IE 8, and IE 9.  I can't reproduce any disappearing header.  If you've made changes to the theme, they might be the reason the header's acting up ... but we can't help you if we can't see/reproduce the problem.  Since the official demo *isn't* broken, I suggest you either link us to your live site or contact the original developer directly.

Comment: Url of my (test)site is http://bit.ly/u2U3S2. Yes, demo site works fine in IE9, so it has something to do with minor changes I've made in the theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded your test site and immediately noticed a couple of issues.  Not 100% sure what exactly is causing the disappearing header, but here are some things to check:

### style-options.php

Your main stylesheet is using `@import url("functions/stylesheets/style-options.php");` to import a stylesheet.  My guess is that it's trying to import some dynamically-generated css.  Unfortunately, this is what that stylesheet contains:

> Deprecated: Function set_magic_quotes_runtime() is deprecated in /home/deb28386n2/domains/jethrowaanders.nl/public_html/test/wp/wp-settings.php on line 32
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/deb28386n2/domains/jethrowaanders.nl/public_html/test/wp/wp-settings.php:32) in /home/deb28386n2/domains/jethrowaanders.nl/public_html/test/wp/wp-content/themes/paperpunch/functions/stylesheets/style-options.php on line 4

It's also returning with a content-type of `text/html`, which IE9 is rejecting altogether as a type mismatch (stylesheets should only be delivered as `text/css`).

### Cufon

Your theme is trying to use a system called Cufon to generate the header and navigation link text.  In modern browsers (not IE), it uses HTML5 canvas to do this.  In IE it switches over to VML (vector markup language).

IE9 *should* still be using canvas, though.  The demo theme from ThemeFoundry is still using canvas on the header ... yours is attempting to use VML.  Why it's switching is likely a change or configuration you made somewhere while customizing the theme.

There are also a couple of other brute-force fixes you can use if you can't narrow down exactly what you changed.  [Here's one](http://www.vfxdude.com/forum/topic/cufon-display-issues-in-ie9-beta-heres-a-fix).

Comment: It's working fine in IE6-8, FF, Opera and Chrome, not IE9, strange. But thanks, I try to figure out what I've done wrong

Comment: That's the thing. The non-IE browsers use Canvas.  IE6-8 use VML.  IE9 is *supposed* to use Canvas because it doesn't support VML ... but on your site, it's not switching over.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran a test on the demo at http://demo.thethemefoundry.com/paperpunch/ and everything looks fine under IE9 I would have to see your site to be able to figure it out.

One thing that may work is if you [defined the IE document type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to an earlier version kinda a cheap trick but it should work.

Add this to your meta `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >`

Comment: Url of my (test)site is http://bit.ly/u2U3S2. Yes, demo site works fine in IE9, so it has something to do with minor changes I've made in the theme